# The problem of modified architecture of Resnet-101

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network, resnet

Recently, I am implementing the ME-Net using pytorch, however, I encounter some problem.
In the ME-Net paper (as attached figure [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1uKRc.png), the top part using ResNet-101 to extract features(using the pretrained ResNet-101 weight on the ImageNet datasets as the initial weight), whose kernel is arithmetic mean.

I use (256,256,11) as the image input, but i am not sure stage0~stage1 belongs to which part in ResNet-101 and can't find the output feature map size in each stage corresponding to the paper.

ME-Net paper:
ME-Net: A Deep Convolutional Neural Network for Extracting Mangrove Using Sentinel-2A Data
https://www.mdpi.com/2072-4292/13/7/1

```
from torchvision import models
res101 = models.resnet101(pretrained=True)

res101.conv1=nn.Conv2d(11, 64, kernel_size=(7, 7), stride=(2, 2), padding=(3, 3), bias=False)
res101.cuda()
summary(res101, (11,256,256)
```

The summary of res101 :

---

```
    Layer (type)               Output Shape         Param #

        Conv2d-1         [-1, 64, 128, 128]          34,496
   BatchNorm2d-2         [-1, 64, 128, 128]             128
          ReLU-3         [-1, 64, 128, 128]               0
     MaxPool2d-4           [-1, 64, 64, 64]               0
        Conv2d-5           [-1, 64, 64, 64]           4,096
   BatchNorm2d-6           [-1, 64, 64, 64]             128
          ReLU-7           [-1, 64, 64, 64]               0
        Conv2d-8           [-1, 64, 64, 64]          36,864
   BatchNorm2d-9           [-1, 64, 64, 64]             128
         ReLU-10           [-1, 64, 64, 64]               0
       Conv2d-11          [-1, 256, 64, 64]          16,384
  BatchNorm2d-12          [-1, 256, 64, 64]             512
       Conv2d-13          [-1, 256, 64, 64]          16,384
  BatchNorm2d-14          [-1, 256, 64, 64]             512
         ReLU-15          [-1, 256, 64, 64]               0
   Bottleneck-16          [-1, 256, 64, 64]               0
       Conv2d-17           [-1, 64, 64, 64]          16,384
  BatchNorm2d-18           [-1, 64, 64, 64]             128
         ReLU-19           [-1, 64, 64, 64]               0
       Conv2d-20           [-1, 64, 64, 64]          36,864
  BatchNorm2d-21           [-1, 64, 64, 64]             128
         ReLU-22           [-1, 64, 64, 64]               0
       Conv2d-23          [-1, 256, 64, 64]          16,384
  BatchNorm2d-24          [-1, 256, 64, 64]             512
         ReLU-25          [-1, 256, 64, 64]               0
   Bottleneck-26          [-1, 256, 64, 64]               0
       Conv2d-27           [-1, 64, 64, 64]          16,384
  BatchNorm2d-28           [-1, 64, 64, 64]             128
         ReLU-29           [-1, 64, 64, 64]               0
       Conv2d-30           [-1, 64, 64, 64]          36,864
  BatchNorm2d-31           [-1, 64, 64, 64]             128
         ReLU-32           [-1, 64, 64, 64]               0
       Conv2d-33          [-1, 256, 64, 64]          16,384
  BatchNorm2d-34          [-1, 256, 64, 64]             512
         ReLU-35          [-1, 256, 64, 64]               0
   Bottleneck-36          [-1, 256, 64, 64]               0
       Conv2d-37          [-1, 128, 64, 64]          32,768
  BatchNorm2d-38          [-1, 128, 64, 64]             256
         ReLU-39          [-1, 128, 64, 64]               0
       Conv2d-40          [-1, 128, 32, 32]         147,456
  BatchNorm2d-41          [-1, 128, 32, 32]             256
         ReLU-42          [-1, 128, 32, 32]               0
       Conv2d-43          [-1, 512, 32, 32]          65,536
  BatchNorm2d-44          [-1, 512, 32, 32]           1,024
       Conv2d-45          [-1, 512, 32, 32]         131,072
  BatchNorm2d-46          [-1, 512, 32, 32]           1,024
         ReLU-47          [-1, 512, 32, 32]               0
   Bottleneck-48          [-1, 512, 32, 32]               0
       Conv2d-49          [-1, 128, 32, 32]          65,536
  BatchNorm2d-50          [-1, 128, 32, 32]             256
         ReLU-51          [-1, 128, 32, 32]               0
       Conv2d-52          [-1, 128, 32, 32]         147,456
  BatchNorm2d-53          [-1, 128, 32, 32]             256
         ReLU-54          [-1, 128, 32, 32]               0
       Conv2d-55          [-1, 512, 32, 32]          65,536
  BatchNorm2d-56          [-1, 512, 32, 32]           1,024
         ReLU-57          [-1, 512, 32, 32]               0
   Bottleneck-58          [-1, 512, 32, 32]               0
       Conv2d-59          [-1, 128, 32, 32]          65,536
  BatchNorm2d-60          [-1, 128, 32, 32]             256
         ReLU-61          [-1, 128, 32, 32]               0
       Conv2d-62          [-1, 128, 32, 32]         147,456
  BatchNorm2d-63          [-1, 128, 32, 32]             256
         ReLU-64          [-1, 128, 32, 32]               0
       Conv2d-65          [-1, 512, 32, 32]          65,536
  BatchNorm2d-66          [-1, 512, 32, 32]           1,024
         ReLU-67          [-1, 512, 32, 32]               0
   Bottleneck-68          [-1, 512, 32, 32]               0
       Conv2d-69          [-1, 128, 32, 32]          65,536
  BatchNorm2d-70          [-1, 128, 32, 32]             256
         ReLU-71          [-1, 128, 32, 32]               0
       Conv2d-72          [-1, 128, 32, 32]         147,456
  BatchNorm2d-73          [-1, 128, 32, 32]             256
         ReLU-74          [-1, 128, 32, 32]               0
       Conv2d-75          [-1, 512, 32, 32]          65,536
  BatchNorm2d-76          [-1, 512, 32, 32]           1,024
         ReLU-77          [-1, 512, 32, 32]               0
   Bottleneck-78          [-1, 512, 32, 32]               0
       Conv2d-79          [-1, 256, 32, 32]         131,072
  BatchNorm2d-80          [-1, 256, 32, 32]             512
         ReLU-81          [-1, 256, 32, 32]               0
       Conv2d-82          [-1, 256, 16, 16]         589,824
  BatchNorm2d-83          [-1, 256, 16, 16]             512
         ReLU-84          [-1, 256, 16, 16]               0
       Conv2d-85         [-1, 1024, 16, 16]         262,144
  BatchNorm2d-86         [-1, 1024, 16, 16]           2,048
       Conv2d-87         [-1, 1024, 16, 16]         524,288
  BatchNorm2d-88         [-1, 1024, 16, 16]           2,048
         ReLU-89         [-1, 1024, 16, 16]               0
   Bottleneck-90         [-1, 1024, 16, 16]               0
       Conv2d-91          [-1, 256, 16, 16]         262,144
  BatchNorm2d-92          [-1, 256, 16, 16]             512
         ReLU-93          [-1, 256, 16, 16]               0
       Conv2d-94          [-1, 256, 16, 16]         589,824
  BatchNorm2d-95          [-1, 256, 16, 16]             512
         ReLU-96          [-1, 256, 16, 16]               0
       Conv2d-97         [-1, 1024, 16, 16]         262,144
  BatchNorm2d-98         [-1, 1024, 16, 16]           2,048
         ReLU-99         [-1, 1024, 16, 16]               0
  Bottleneck-100         [-1, 1024, 16, 16]               0
      Conv2d-101          [-1, 256, 16, 16]         262,144
 BatchNorm2d-102          [-1, 256, 16, 16]             512
        ReLU-103          [-1, 256, 16, 16]               0
      Conv2d-104          [-1, 256, 16, 16]         589,824
 BatchNorm2d-105          [-1, 256, 16, 16]             512
        ReLU-106          [-1, 256, 16, 16]               0
      Conv2d-107         [-1, 1024, 16, 16]         262,144
 BatchNorm2d-108         [-1, 1024, 16, 16]           2,048
        ReLU-109         [-1, 1024, 16, 16]               0
  Bottleneck-110         [-1, 1024, 16, 16]               0
      Conv2d-111          [-1, 256, 16, 16]         262,144
 BatchNorm2d-112          [-1, 256, 16, 16]             512
        ReLU-113          [-1, 256, 16, 16]               0
      Conv2d-114          [-1, 256, 16, 16]         589,824
 BatchNorm2d-115          [-1, 256, 16, 16]             512
        ReLU-116          [-1, 256, 16, 16]               0
      Conv2d-117         [-1, 1024, 16, 16]         262,144
 BatchNorm2d-118         [-1, 1024, 16, 16]           2,048
        ReLU-119         [-1, 1024, 16, 16]               0
  Bottleneck-120         [-1, 1024, 16, 16]               0
      Conv2d-121          [-1, 256, 16, 16]         262,144
 BatchNorm2d-122          [-1, 256, 16, 16]             512
        ReLU-123          [-1, 256, 16, 16]               0
      Conv2d-124          [-1, 256, 16, 16]         589,824
 BatchNorm2d-125          [-1, 256, 16, 16]             512
        ReLU-126          [-1, 256, 16, 16]               0
      Conv2d-127         [-1, 1024, 16, 16]         262,144
 BatchNorm2d-128         [-1, 1024, 16, 16]           2,048
        ReLU-129         [-1, 1024, 16, 16]               0
  Bottleneck-130         [-1, 1024, 16, 16]               0
      Conv2d-131          [-1, 256, 16, 16]         262,144
 BatchNorm2d-132          [-1, 256, 16, 16]             512
        ReLU-133          [-1, 256, 16, 16]               0
      Conv2d-134          [-1, 256, 16, 16]         589,824
 BatchNorm2d-135          [-1, 256, 16, 16]             512
        ReLU-136          [-1, 256, 16, 16]               0
      Conv2d-137         [-1, 1024, 16, 16]         262,144
 BatchNorm2d-138         [-1, 1024, 16, 16]           2,048
        ReLU-139         [-1, 1024, 16, 16]               0
  Bottleneck-140         [-1, 1024, 16, 16]               0
      Conv2d-141          [-1, 256, 16, 16]         262,144
 BatchNorm2d-142          [-1, 256, 16, 16]             512
        ReLU-143          [-1, 256, 16, 16]               0
      Conv2d-144          [-1, 256, 16, 16]         589,824
 BatchNorm2d-145          [-1, 256, 16, 16]             512
        ReLU-146          [-1, 256, 16, 16]               0
      Conv2d-147         [-1, 1024, 16, 16]         262,144
 BatchNorm2d-148         [-1, 1024, 16, 16]           2,048
        ReLU-149         [-1, 1024, 16, 16]               0
  Bottleneck-150         [-1, 1024, 16, 16]               0
      Conv2d-151          [-1, 256, 16, 16]         262,144
 BatchNorm2d-152          [-1, 256, 16, 16]             512
        ReLU-153          [-1, 256, 16, 16]               0
      Conv2d-154          [-1, 256, 16, 16]         589,824
 BatchNorm2d-155          [-1, 256, 16, 16]             512
        ReLU-156          [-1, 256, 16, 16]               0
      Conv2d-157         [-1, 1024, 16, 16]         262,144
 BatchNorm2d-158         [-1, 1024, 16, 16]           2,048
        ReLU-159         [-1, 1024, 16, 16]               0
  Bottleneck-160         [-1, 1024, 16, 16]               0
      Conv2d-161          [-1, 256, 16, 16]         262,144
 BatchNorm2d-162          [-1, 256, 16, 16]             512
        ReLU-163          [-1, 256, 16, 16]               0
      Conv2d-164          [-1, 256, 16, 16]         589,824
 BatchNorm2d-165          [-1, 256, 16, 16]             512
        ReLU-166          [-1, 256, 16, 16]               0
      Conv2d-167         [-1, 1024, 16, 16]         262,144
 BatchNorm2d-168         [-1, 1024, 16, 16]           2,048
        ReLU-169         [-1, 1024, 16, 16]               0
  Bottleneck-170         [-1, 1024, 16, 16]               0
      Conv2d-171          [-1, 256, 16, 16]         262,144
 BatchNorm2d-172          [-1, 256, 16, 16]             512
        ReLU-173          [-1, 256, 16, 16]               0
      Conv2d-174          [-1, 256, 16, 16]         589,824
 BatchNorm2d-175          [-1, 256, 16, 16]             512
        ReLU-176          [-1, 256, 16, 16]               0
      Conv2d-177         [-1, 1024, 16, 16]         262,144
 BatchNorm2d-178         [-1, 1024, 16, 16]           2,048
        ReLU-179         [-1, 1024, 16, 16]               0
  Bottleneck-180         [-1, 1024, 16, 16]               0
      Conv2d-181          [-1, 256, 16, 16]         262,144
 BatchNorm2d-182          [-1, 256, 16, 16]             512
        ReLU-183          [-1, 256, 16, 16]               0
      Conv2d-184          [-1, 256, 16, 16]         589,824
 BatchNorm2d-185          [-1, 256, 16, 16]             512
        ReLU-186          [-1, 256, 16, 16]               0
      Conv2d-187         [-1, 1024, 16, 16]         262,144
 BatchNorm2d-188         [-1, 1024, 16, 16]           2,048
        ReLU-189         [-1, 1024, 16, 16]               0
  Bottleneck-190         [-1, 1024, 16, 16]               0
      Conv2d-191          [-1, 256, 16, 16]         262,144
 BatchNorm2d-192          [-1, 256, 16, 16]             512
        ReLU-193          [-1, 256, 16, 16]               0
      Conv2d-194          [-1, 256, 16, 16]         589,824
 BatchNorm2d-195          [-1, 256, 16, 16]             512
        ReLU-196          [-1, 256, 16, 16]               0
      Conv2d-197         [-1, 1024, 16, 16]         262,144
 BatchNorm2d-198         [-1, 1024, 16, 16]           2,048
        ReLU-199         [-1, 1024, 16, 16]               0
  Bottleneck-200         [-1, 1024, 16, 16]               0
      Conv2d-201          [-1, 256, 16, 16]         262,144
 BatchNorm2d-202          [-1, 256, 16, 16]             512
        ReLU-203          [-1, 256, 16, 16]               0
      Conv2d-204          [-1, 256, 16, 16]         589,824
 BatchNorm2d-205          [-1, 256, 16, 16]             512
        ReLU-206          [-1, 256, 16, 16]               0
      Conv2d-207         [-1, 1024, 16, 16]         262,144
 BatchNorm2d-208         [-1, 1024, 16, 16]           2,048
        ReLU-209         [-1, 1024, 16, 16]               0
  Bottleneck-210         [-1, 1024, 16, 16]               0
      Conv2d-211          [-1, 256, 16, 16]         262,144
 BatchNorm2d-212          [-1, 256, 16, 16]             512
        ReLU-213          [-1, 256, 16, 16]               0
      Conv2d-214          [-1, 256, 16, 16]         589,824
 BatchNorm2d-215          [-1, 256, 16, 16]             512
        ReLU-216          [-1, 256, 16, 16]               0
      Conv2d-217         [-1, 1024, 16, 16]         262,144
 BatchNorm2d-218         [-1, 1024, 16, 16]           2,048
        ReLU-219         [-1, 1024, 16, 16]               0
  Bottleneck-220         [-1, 1024, 16, 16]               0
      Conv2d-221          [-1, 256, 16, 16]         262,144
 BatchNorm2d-222          [-1, 256, 16, 16]             512
        ReLU-223          [-1, 256, 16, 16]               0
      Conv2d-224          [-1, 256, 16, 16]         589,824
 BatchNorm2d-225          [-1, 256, 16, 16]             512
        ReLU-226          [-1, 256, 16, 16]               0
      Conv2d-227         [-1, 1024, 16, 16]         262,144
 BatchNorm2d-228         [-1, 1024, 16, 16]           2,048
        ReLU-229         [-1, 1024, 16, 16]               0
  Bottleneck-230         [-1, 1024, 16, 16]               0
      Conv2d-231          [-1, 256, 16, 16]         262,144
 BatchNorm2d-232          [-1, 256, 16, 16]             512
        ReLU-233          [-1, 256, 16, 16]               0
      Conv2d-234          [-1, 256, 16, 16]         589,824
 BatchNorm2d-235          [-1, 256, 16, 16]             512
        ReLU-236          [-1, 256, 16, 16]               0
      Conv2d-237         [-1, 1024, 16, 16]         262,144
 BatchNorm2d-238         [-1, 1024, 16, 16]           2,048
        ReLU-239         [-1, 1024, 16, 16]               0
  Bottleneck-240         [-1, 1024, 16, 16]               0
      Conv2d-241          [-1, 256, 16, 16]         262,144
 BatchNorm2d-242          [-1, 256, 16, 16]             512
        ReLU-243          [-1, 256, 16, 16]               0
      Conv2d-244          [-1, 256, 16, 16]         589,824
 BatchNorm2d-245          [-1, 256, 16, 16]             512
        ReLU-246          [-1, 256, 16, 16]               0
      Conv2d-247         [-1, 1024, 16, 16]         262,144
 BatchNorm2d-248         [-1, 1024, 16, 16]           2,048
        ReLU-249         [-1, 1024, 16, 16]               0
  Bottleneck-250         [-1, 1024, 16, 16]               0
      Conv2d-251          [-1, 256, 16, 16]         262,144
 BatchNorm2d-252          [-1, 256, 16, 16]             512
        ReLU-253          [-1, 256, 16, 16]               0
      Conv2d-254          [-1, 256, 16, 16]         589,824
 BatchNorm2d-255          [-1, 256, 16, 16]             512
        ReLU-256          [-1, 256, 16, 16]               0
      Conv2d-257         [-1, 1024, 16, 16]         262,144
 BatchNorm2d-258         [-1, 1024, 16, 16]           2,048
        ReLU-259         [-1, 1024, 16, 16]               0
  Bottleneck-260         [-1, 1024, 16, 16]               0
      Conv2d-261          [-1, 256, 16, 16]         262,144
 BatchNorm2d-262          [-1, 256, 16, 16]             512
        ReLU-263          [-1, 256, 16, 16]               0
      Conv2d-264          [-1, 256, 16, 16]         589,824
 BatchNorm2d-265          [-1, 256, 16, 16]             512
        ReLU-266          [-1, 256, 16, 16]               0
      Conv2d-267         [-1, 1024, 16, 16]         262,144
 BatchNorm2d-268         [-1, 1024, 16, 16]           2,048
        ReLU-269         [-1, 1024, 16, 16]               0
  Bottleneck-270         [-1, 1024, 16, 16]               0
      Conv2d-271          [-1, 256, 16, 16]         262,144
 BatchNorm2d-272          [-1, 256, 16, 16]             512
        ReLU-273          [-1, 256, 16, 16]               0
      Conv2d-274          [-1, 256, 16, 16]         589,824
 BatchNorm2d-275          [-1, 256, 16, 16]             512
        ReLU-276          [-1, 256, 16, 16]               0
      Conv2d-277         [-1, 1024, 16, 16]         262,144
 BatchNorm2d-278         [-1, 1024, 16, 16]           2,048
        ReLU-279         [-1, 1024, 16, 16]               0
  Bottleneck-280         [-1, 1024, 16, 16]               0
      Conv2d-281          [-1, 256, 16, 16]         262,144
 BatchNorm2d-282          [-1, 256, 16, 16]             512
        ReLU-283          [-1, 256, 16, 16]               0
      Conv2d-284          [-1, 256, 16, 16]         589,824
 BatchNorm2d-285          [-1, 256, 16, 16]             512
        ReLU-286          [-1, 256, 16, 16]               0
      Conv2d-287         [-1, 1024, 16, 16]         262,144
 BatchNorm2d-288         [-1, 1024, 16, 16]           2,048
        ReLU-289         [-1, 1024, 16, 16]               0
  Bottleneck-290         [-1, 1024, 16, 16]               0
      Conv2d-291          [-1, 256, 16, 16]         262,144
 BatchNorm2d-292          [-1, 256, 16, 16]             512
        ReLU-293          [-1, 256, 16, 16]               0
      Conv2d-294          [-1, 256, 16, 16]         589,824
 BatchNorm2d-295          [-1, 256, 16, 16]             512
        ReLU-296          [-1, 256, 16, 16]               0
      Conv2d-297         [-1, 1024, 16, 16]         262,144
 BatchNorm2d-298         [-1, 1024, 16, 16]           2,048
        ReLU-299         [-1, 1024, 16, 16]               0
  Bottleneck-300         [-1, 1024, 16, 16]               0
      Conv2d-301          [-1, 256, 16, 16]         262,144
 BatchNorm2d-302          [-1, 256, 16, 16]             512
        ReLU-303          [-1, 256, 16, 16]               0
      Conv2d-304          [-1, 256, 16, 16]         589,824
 BatchNorm2d-305          [-1, 256, 16, 16]             512
        ReLU-306          [-1, 256, 16, 16]               0
      Conv2d-307         [-1, 1024, 16, 16]         262,144
 BatchNorm2d-308         [-1, 1024, 16, 16]           2,048
        ReLU-309         [-1, 1024, 16, 16]               0
  Bottleneck-310         [-1, 1024, 16, 16]               0
      Conv2d-311          [-1, 512, 16, 16]         524,288
 BatchNorm2d-312          [-1, 512, 16, 16]           1,024
        ReLU-313          [-1, 512, 16, 16]               0
      Conv2d-314            [-1, 512, 8, 8]       2,359,296
 BatchNorm2d-315            [-1, 512, 8, 8]           1,024
        ReLU-316            [-1, 512, 8, 8]               0
      Conv2d-317           [-1, 2048, 8, 8]       1,048,576
 BatchNorm2d-318           [-1, 2048, 8, 8]           4,096
      Conv2d-319           [-1, 2048, 8, 8]       2,097,152
 BatchNorm2d-320           [-1, 2048, 8, 8]           4,096
        ReLU-321           [-1, 2048, 8, 8]               0
  Bottleneck-322           [-1, 2048, 8, 8]               0
      Conv2d-323            [-1, 512, 8, 8]       1,048,576
 BatchNorm2d-324            [-1, 512, 8, 8]           1,024
        ReLU-325            [-1, 512, 8, 8]               0
      Conv2d-326            [-1, 512, 8, 8]       2,359,296
 BatchNorm2d-327            [-1, 512, 8, 8]           1,024
        ReLU-328            [-1, 512, 8, 8]               0
      Conv2d-329           [-1, 2048, 8, 8]       1,048,576
 BatchNorm2d-330           [-1, 2048, 8, 8]           4,096
        ReLU-331           [-1, 2048, 8, 8]               0
  Bottleneck-332           [-1, 2048, 8, 8]               0
      Conv2d-333            [-1, 512, 8, 8]       1,048,576
 BatchNorm2d-334            [-1, 512, 8, 8]           1,024
        ReLU-335            [-1, 512, 8, 8]               0
      Conv2d-336            [-1, 512, 8, 8]       2,359,296
 BatchNorm2d-337            [-1, 512, 8, 8]           1,024
        ReLU-338            [-1, 512, 8, 8]               0
      Conv2d-339           [-1, 2048, 8, 8]       1,048,576
 BatchNorm2d-340           [-1, 2048, 8, 8]           4,096
        ReLU-341           [-1, 2048, 8, 8]               0
  Bottleneck-342           [-1, 2048, 8, 8]               0
 AdaptiveAvgPool2d-343     [-1, 2048, 1, 1]               0
      Linear-344                 [-1, 1000]       2,049,000
```

I think the output feature map in stage0 is Layer:ReLU-3; the output feature map in stage1 is Layer:ReLU-32; the output feature map in stage2 is Layer:ReLU-81; the output feature map in stage3 is Layer:ReLU-313; I can't find the output feature maps in stage4 and stage5 in the size of (8,8,1024) and (4,4,2048).

-----Update below-----

To acquire the feature map in stage0~stage5, I use the code below:

```
stage5 = nn.Sequential(*list(res101.children())[:-2])    
stage4 = nn.Sequential(*list(res101.children())[:-3])      
stage3 = nn.Sequential(*list(res101.children())[:-4])    
stage2 = nn.Sequential(*list(res101.children())[:-5])    
stage1 = nn.Sequential(*list(res101.children())[:-6])    
stage0 = nn.Sequential(*list(res101.children())[:-7])
```

However, the stage0~5 seems just represent the architecture.

How can I get their feature maps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is easier to check PyTorch’s source code for troubles like this one, see [here](https://pytorch.org/vision/stable/_modules/torchvision/models/resnet.html#resnet101).

Look at the `ResNet` class (which is used to create different variants via factory-like functions) for clues.

In this case, respective layers would be:

- `conv1` (`stage0`)
- max pooled output of `conv1` (`stage1`), this one is assumed by the shapes
- `layer1` (`stage2`)
- `layer2`
- `layer3`
- `layer4`(`stage5`)

Also, you might use `print(res101)` to see all of the blocks for easier debugging as it has a hierarchical structure.

### Obtaining features

You should use PyTorch FX for that (see [here](https://pytorch.org/blog/FX-feature-extraction-torchvision/)).

In your case it would be something along these lines:

```
from torchvision.models.feature_extractor import create_feature_extractor

extractor = create_feature_extractor(
    model,
    return_nodes=[
        ”conv1”, 
        “maxpool”, 
        “layer1”,
        “layer2”,
        “layer3”,
        “layer4”,
    ]
)

features = extractor(inputs)
```

Features should be a `dict` with `keys` being names of the layers specified above and `values` being resulting `tensors`.

Comment: Thank you for your response!
I would like to ask which layer corresponds to stage5?
Thank you! : )

Comment: If I want to acquire the feature maps in stage0~stage5, is the code update in the article proper? or there is a better way to implement it? (I update this problem in the article.)

Comment: @MandyChu See my updated answer

Comment: Thank you! But I have trouble using torchvision.models.feature_extractor. The error is No module named 'torchvision.models.feature_extractor'. I change the line to "from torchvision.models.feature_extraction import create_feature_extractor", and the error still happen: No module named 'torchvision.models.feature_extraction'.